# Sending logs with bug reports: how to defend against easy exploits like malicious file enlargement?

Tags: logging, file-upload

When a crash occurs or when a user reports a bug, I'd like to **send my application's logs** to a **cloud service** (Firebase).

But I've just realised that there are tons of **kindergarten level exploits**. For example:

- they can make these logs **tremendous sized**, causing me **huge bills**.

Some examples:

- 1. If the log are accessible/unauthenticated then it's trivial.
- 2. If the logs are i.e. signed by the application somehow... they can still generate huge ones by just using the application.

I thought about **limiting the file size** by removing lines from the logs by some prioritizing until they are below the size limit.

- But then debugging can be a magical beast, there is a chance that we've just deleted a seemingly unimportant, yet now important line.

And then let's say I implemented some fine logic to keep it under a size limit.

- The user can still send reports an unlimited amount of time.

I guess I could add some **IP limiting**, but that could harm the good users by not letting them send more than 6 bug reports / hour.

My application won't be a hit, so I guess I should just **prepare for the script kiddies**.

But even so, my question is: What should I be aware of? Thanks!

Comment: You must have an exceedingly grim view of your application's code if you expect people to send more then 6 bug reports per hour :)

Comment: Yeah, maybe that estimation wasn't the best. But I guess when I send the build (a game) to my internal tester, there's a chance that he will report issues/unpolished stuff/remarks that frequently. But I guess in that build I could remove the limitation :D